# Undeleting my removed post

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My post [Gravitational shifts of frequency in general relativity and classical physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155372/2451) was first closed by five users, and finally deleted as “off-topic”. This post has consisted in a comparison between relativistic and classical solutions for three kinds of frequency shifts noticed in gravitational field, all of them well-known for a long time, therefore indisputably inside PSE *mainstream* physics. Downright fanny, my previous post [A proof for Newtonian origin of residual perihelion advances in solar system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153194/2451) has also consisted in a comparison between relativistic and classical solutions for another phenomenon claimed to be an experimental test of general relativity, but nobody considered it as “off-topic”, although in this case the classical solution has been indeed somewhat a novelty.
As in my opinion the ill-will of my censors is evident, I ask for undeleting my post abusively removed.

Comment: emotive statements such as "abusive" and "censors" will not help your cause

Comment: FYI, the question was automatically deleted by the [Community](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). Let me go ahead and undelete it for the sake of this meta post.

Comment: Sava, I assure you there is no ill will against you. I haven't looked at the posts yet to determine their on-topicness yet, but we are human and sometimes we make mistakes if this was a mistake at all. That said, the fact that the one post was not closed when you consider it to be more off-topic than the one that was should indicate we have no malice towards you. We at physics.se love our new users (<3), it's just that sometimes unfortunate things happen to them. If what happened to you was unjust, we feel for you and we'll do what we can to fix it. If we disagree, we'll give you a reason

Comment: I undeleted the post again.

Comment: @SabreTooth - The incriminated words express a reality. Forbidding a post just owing to your idiosyncrasies really is an abusive censorship. And some of these intolerant young men could be the future implacable censors in universities, research centers, journal, publishing houses. If you are skeptic in this regard, please read that Declaration of Academic Freedom available on Progress in Physics site. It is a bitter testimony of an insider, after a life in the real system.

Comment: @Jim - I love you too, Jim. Cheers!

Comment: @Sava I am not talking about that - I am referring to this post only.

Answer (score 8):

The deletion of your post happened *automatically*, since it is *closed*, has no answers, a negative score, and was closed more than 9 days ago. This is the [automatic deletion routine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/263383) running across all SE sites, and represents no particular ill-will towards your question in particular, and hence, even if undeleted, it will be deleted again when this routine runs the next time (it runs once every day, I think).